# Statistics and Proof or decisions?

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-explanation

Alice and Bess are playing a game in which Alice thinks of a number in the set A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} and Bess has to guess what it is. If she guesses correctly, she wins; if she guesses incorrectly,
Alice increases or decreases her number by 1 (keeping it in the set A) before Bess’ next guess.
What is the smallest number k such that Bess can guarantee to win within k guesses?

I think I have solved it by trial and error of sort and concluded that the minimum value of k=8; however I'm wondering if there is a way to solve algebraically.

Comment: Bess? What happened to good old Bob? :(

Comment: @Bemte, Alice caught him sharing secrets with Eve.